# Delete an entry from firebase realtime database with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I need help on how to remove a firebase entry

I have the following code in the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('deleteDriver_btn').onclick = function() {
     firebase.database().ref('drivers').child('driver_num').on('value', function(driverSnapshot) {
     var driverChildSnapshot = driverSnapshot.val();
     var queryRef = firebase.database().ref('drivers').orderByChild('driver_num').equalTo(dataRow);
               queryRef.remove();
     });
};
```

I get an error saying that queryRef.remove() is not a function.

Firebase entry goes like:

```
---driver
     --AKSJDIWDKSADKAWsdak <---- want to delete this and the data underneath
         -driver_num
         -first_name
         -last_name
     --akdjwoajdksafksndjiw <---- want to retain this
         -driver_num
         -first_name
         -last_name
```

Comment: I think it's because your equalTo call returns a Query object rather than a ref https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equal-to 

So if you inspected queryRef it would be a Query rather than a ref like you're expecting. If you add `.ref` to the end to get the reference itself and then call remove does that work? e.g `queryRef.ref.remove();` Also not these also look like async operations, so perhaps you're missing a callback or need to use `async/await`

Comment: I tried the `queryRef.ref.remove();` and it removed all the children under `drivers`.

Comment: could you use limitToFirst to get the first result possibly on the query or the ref? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#limittofirst

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#limittofirst

Comment: I finally found out how thanks to the links. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found my answer thanks to the hint @TommyBs sent about the references. I just query to extract the key and then initiate .ref().remove()

```
document.getElementById('deleteDriver_btn').onclick = function() {
       var refe = firebase.database().ref("drivers");
       var diskey = "";

       refe.orderByChild("driver_num").equalTo(dataRow).on("child_added", function(snapshots) 
            {
                diskey = snapshots.key;
            });
       firebase.database().ref("drivers/" + diskey).remove();
};
```